# How do I create custom Widget for my c# app

Tags: c#

How do I create custom widget for my c# application.

Example :

I wrote an app that shows in Windows 10 menu just like other apps (example firefox) - 
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqvZS.png)

How can I create custom "widget"? To show on my app with some from current state of application.
This application is running on user PC all the time, each hour it refresh some informations and I want them to display on this "widget".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean like a system tray icon and when you click on it, you get a status of the program... or do you want it to show when you hover over the taskbar icon?

Comment: Something like the "weather app" which have "dynamic icon" showing basic weather on the tray icon, just when you open the app you get more to choose from.

Comment: Do you mean like the Weather app which shows a panel on the start menu and updates itself from time to time?
If you want to do something like this, the key words to search for are "Live Tile".
The icons on the start screen are called "Tiles" and the ones that are dynamic are "Live".
Here's a site that talks about them and has a bit of sample code which might lead you in the right direction.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn857365.aspx

Comment: @PhilRogers this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for help, unfortunately I can't mark it as "answer" because it is a comment. If you answer with this I will approve it.

Answer (score 1):

The icons on the Windows start screen are known as "Tiles".  The tiles that are dynamic are known as "Live Tiles".  I share your frustration about not knowing what to search for in the search engines when you don't know what the correct terminology is.

Although I have never created a Live Tile, I did find this site:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn857365.aspx
which discusses Live Tiles and has some sample code, which might point you in the right direction.
It doesn't look like a complete solution for what you are looking for, but it should give you enough background to know what to search for.

Comment: Do you know if I can use Live Tile in WinForms app ? I'm already recognizing User OS - for Windows 10 I want to add Live Tile to Start Menu, otherwise don't do anything.

Comment: Updating a live tile is more likely to be handled by a separate, background assembly, so I see no reason why you couldn't use one in Windows Forms.
A quick search uncovered this on the Microsoft Dev Center site:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/update-a-live-tile-from-a-background-task.